# how to enable second cache level in doctrine?

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I enabled second cache level in my config file:

```
  orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        second_level_cache:
            region_cache_driver:
                type:                 array
                host:                 ~
                port:                 ~
                instance_class:       ~
                class:                ~
                id:                   ~
                namespace:            ~
                cache_provider:       ~
            region_lock_lifetime: 600
            log_enabled:          true
            region_lifetime:      0
            enabled:              true
```

in my entity that need to cache, add new annotation (Cache) like:

```
/**
 * Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity")
 * @ORM\Cache(usage="READ_ONLY", region="entity_cache")
 */
class Entity
{

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
  private $id;

}
```

But show it now:
[image]

so, first what do mean cache hits, cache misses and cache puts? 
and second what happened now and how can cache my entity?

Answer (score 9):

**Nov 7, 2018:**

Firstly here's an important warning from Doctrine:

"The second level cache functionality is marked as experimental for now. It is a very complex feature and we cannot guarantee yet that it works stable in all cases."

So,

> "how can cache my entity?"

1. You need to set up a cache provider (redis, memcached, so on)
2. add doctrine and cache provider dependencies with composer require
3. configure cache provider
4. enable second lvl cache in app/config.yml

   ```
   doctrine:
     orm:
       second_level_cache:
         enabled: true
   ```
5. You should specify caching regions for each type of data (entity data, collecion data or query data) too:

   ```
   regions:
     entity_that_rarely_changes:
       lifetime: 86400
       cache_driver: redis
       type: service
       id: snc_second_level_cache
   ```
6. Config your entity/entities:

   - Choose a caching mode ("readonly" is the default one)
   - and a region (see above)

     ```
      /**
      * @Cache(usage="READ_ONLY", region="my_entity_region")
      */
      class MyEntity
     ```
7. And finally: your queries:

   ```
   $em->persist(new MyEntity($name));
   $em->flush();
   $em->clear(); // clear em
   $item1  = $em->find('MyEntity', 1); // Retrieve item from cache
   $item1->setName("newname");
   $em->persist($item1);
   $em->flush(); // update row and update cache
   $em->clear(); // clear em
   $item2  = $em->find('MyEntity', 1); // Retrieve item from cache
   ```

> "what do mean cache hits, cache misses and cache puts"

- hits: the item is in the (declared region's) cache, so u dont need to query the db
- missed: the item is not in the (declared region's) cache, so u need to query the db
- puts: how many cacheable entries put in the cache (region).

You should check your Entity cache region paramter in

```
@Cache(usage="READ_ONLY", region="my_entity_region")
```

and your config yml file, for example:

```
regions:
  my_entity_region:
    cache_driver: redis
    lifetime: 3600
```

If (the names of) the regions are different, the entity cache will be "missed" always.

I use a lot of external source, like [Doctrine 2 documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html#the-second-level-cache).
You should do the same ;)

Answer (score 9):

Tested on Symfony 5.1, you do not need to add any bundle or package. All you have to do is something close to:

```yaml
# config/packages/dev/cache.yaml
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: redis://localhost
```

```yaml
# config/packages/dev/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        second_level_cache:
            enabled: true
            region_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.second_level_cache_pool
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.second_level_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
```

And on your entities for example:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Cache
 */
class Category { ... }
```

Comment: It works. Is it possibile to define a cache duration?

Comment: I don't know - but maybe you can find something in the docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/second-level-cache.html

Comment: You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine.second_level_cache_pool".